# Making notes next to items

Tags: enumerate

As a teacher of several years, I am constantly revising/changing quizzes and test as needs change.  I try to embed the question, solution, and auxiliary information all into the tex so that I can cut and paste problems between assessments and retain all of the information.

Some of the auxiliary information is how to grade the question so that when I print the solution key, it also has information about how to deduct points for various incorrect answers depending on how egregious the error is.

In a multiple choice problem, for example, while 1 answer is the right one (full credit), the incorrect answers can represent varying degrees of knowledge (or lack of knowledge).  Shown below is one such problem:

[image]

How do I format the handwritten part of this image?  I don't want it to be at the level of the "2 pts" -- I don't want to format it using marginpar.

One solution would be to have the handwritten part be a fixed distance from the edge of the page, but farther from the edge than the marginpar.  A better solution would be to have it track the indentation so that it was beside the item number at whatever depth that item was.

Finally, I do NOT want to put it in the \item[].  The goal is to have something that I can print for the students without grading information, and then have something where the formatting of the underlying test does not change, but the grading information is overlayed in available space.  In order to create the MWE below, I have not included the actual definition of \answerBox which in the real code does not change the formatting and is triggered by a flag at the beginning of the document that indicates whether I'm printing the answerkey or the student version.

MWE for the non-handwritten part:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.1in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}

\reversemarginpar

\newtcolorbox{myansbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
  oversize,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,left=8mm,interior hidden,
  colframe=red,nobeforeafter=,#1}%

\newcommand\answerBox[1]{%
  \begin{myansbox} %
     #1 %
  \end{myansbox} %
}%

\begin{document}

What is the difference between a square and a rectangle? \marginpar{[2 pts]}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Something silly.
\item Something more silly.
\answerBox{\item The right answer.}
\item None of the above.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to use a special document class that was made for this use case. You can search CTAN for suitable classes (keyword multiple choice or exam). The `exam` class for example seems to offer many possibilities (https://ctan.org/pkg/exam)

Comment: I might consider `todonotes` for this. Doesn't give you exactly the formatting you want: but it's off the shelf and very easy to turn on and off depending on whether you print draft or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should satisfy your requirements, even though technically it does use `\marginpar`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.1in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}

\reversemarginpar

\newtcolorbox{myansbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
  oversize,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,left=8mm,interior hidden,
  colframe=red,nobeforeafter=,#1}%

\newcommand\answerBox[1]{\ifanswers
  \par\vskip\itemsep\begin{myansbox}%
     #1
  \end{myansbox}%
\else
  #1
\fi}

\newif\ifanswers

\newcommand{\marginleft}[1]{\ifanswers
  \marginpar{\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{#1}\hskip\marginparsep}}}%
\fi}

\answerstrue% turn on \marginparleft

\begin{document}

What is the difference between a square and a rectangle? \marginpar{[2 pts]}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Something silly.
\marginleft{-1}
\item Something more silly.
\marginleft{-1.5}
\answerBox{\item The right answer.}
\item None of the above.
\marginleft{-2}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My chief concern with this is that I wanted the grading information next to the \item rather than on the left side of the page.  Based on your code, however, I wrote the following which seems to put it where I was thinking of.  I don't know how many rules of good coding practice I have violated.  Thanks for your help. \marginpar{\textcolor{red}{\hfill\hspace{\itemindent}\rlap\smash{#1}}}%

Comment: BTW, the \smash is probably overkill, but since I was using \parbox instead of \makebox, it seemed like a good idea.